# How are formulas derived from these lines of code?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, formula, time-complexity

I'm going over the following book - [http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-4th-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) and one of the sections talks about deriving formulas from code to estimate performance.

For example, Line D's formula is "N<sup>3</sup>/6 - N<sup>2</sup>/2 + N/3".
I can see that three "N"s are for three for loops. And how cubed and squared are derived. But why is "N<sup>3</sup>/6" and why subtraction and then addition?

[image: Performance Calculation]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to make the numbers concrete, and trace through the whole program the long way (as it were) putting concrete numbers to each of the quantities you're confused about.

So in this case, if N is (arbitrarily) 10, then what happens?

Well, for the A block, it doesn't matter: that executes once.

For the B block, it does matter: i starts at 0, and executes until and including i=9, for a total of 10 executions, but N is 10.

For the C block, it gets trickier:  When i is 0, j initializes to 1, and executes until and including j=9, for a sub-total of 9 executions.  Then the next time through, i=1, to j initializes to 2, and executes 8 times, etc.  All total, it executes 9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=45 times.  But that's (N^2-N)/2.

The D and the E block follow the same way.

That said, you shouldn't have to laboriously work your way through every example, like that.  The two answers above mine are perfectly correct and perfectly succinct.  For little loops like these, I usually think geometrically:  The B block is like marking out notches on a ruler, which is measuring length.  The C block is like marking out squares on a grid, first a row of 9, then a row of 8, etc.  It's sort of like measuring area, and in this case, the area looks like a triangle, which has an area proportional to N^2.

If my geometrical analogy doesn't work for you, that's okay.  Do enough of these and you'll hopefully get an intuitive framework.

Comment: Thanks, you explained that really well.

Answer (score 3):

We're only looking at the possibilities when i < j < k, which isn't all N^3 possibilities.  The number of possibilities for 0 <= i < j < k < N is N choose 3, which is equal to N^3/6 - N^2/2 + N/3.

Comment: For "N^3/6" where does number 6 come from?

Comment: It's what you get if you do the math; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient.

Comment: In particular, using the formula n choose k = n!/k!(n-k)!, you get that N choose 3 is N(N-1)(N-2)/(3*2*1) = (N^3 - 3N^2 + 2N)/6.

Comment: Thanks for the link Louis, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because the loop limit for the `j` loop is derived from the current value of `i`, and the limit for the `k` loop is derived from the current value of `j`.  If you work out all the maths, that is the expression you end up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can also derive the frequency of *line D* by solving the following summation:

[image]

Apply the appropriate formulas listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities) (first two sections).